# diagonal matrix of a matrix with numpy and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix (n*1) and I want to make a diagonal matrix with it.
but I can't construct it with numpy.
I tried each methods in numpy such as methods in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-3ad4144208bdb8910ff1488c3e5bcd93e764dbc4)

Comment: Is it an `np.matrix` or an `np.array`? And do you want a dense or a sparse diagonal matrix?

Comment: it's np.matrix. and I think it is sparse.

Comment: What do you mean with making a diagonal matrix with it? Diagonalizing it (by searching for eigenvalues) or just taking out the diagonal part of the matrix and creating a matrix with it which is otherwise zero?

Comment: just taking out the diagonal part of the matrix and creating a matrix with it which is otherwise zero

Comment: t = np.mat('[1;2;3]')

t1 = np.array(t.conj().T).squeeze()

it can help to solve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([1,2,3])
mat = numpy.diag(arr)
print(mat)
>>> 
[[1 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 3]]
```

Comment: it's a numpy array but I have a numpy matrix

Comment: @Divuneh: then call `asarray` on your matrix. Matrices aren't worth the trouble.