# Creating inverse and diagonal of numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to do inverse of numpy array,

```
from numpy import mat
from numpy import *
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
d =array ([  (0, 1,  2,  3,  4),
             ( 5,  6,  7,  8,  9),
             (10, 11, 12, 13, 14)])

print d.T
print d.I
print d.diagonal
#above line gives <built-in method diagonal of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7fdf40a263f0>
print numpy.linalg.inv(d)
```

I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'I'
```

any suggestion for this to get inverse and diagonal?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178061/diagonal-matrix-of-a-matrix-with-numpy-and-scipy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638895/inverse-of-a-matrix-using-numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing all these imports:

```
from numpy import mat
from numpy import *
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
```

to just one:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then you can do

```
d = np.array(...)
# d = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
M = np.matrix(d)  
M.I   # a matrix has an I property, but an array does not
d.diagonal()  # diagonal is a method, not a property
np.diagonal(d)  # diagonal is also a function
```

`np.linalg.inv(d)` does not work - it gives an error objecting that the array is not square.  So evidently `M.I` is returning a different kind of inverse.  See my note below about `pinv`.

`numpy` (and Python in general) has functions, methods, and properties (attributes).  Are the distinctions clear?

Many numpy functions end up calling the corresponding method for the main array object.  Usually that doesn't matter much, except as a calling convenience.

`np.matrix` is one subclass that has many of its own methods.  Note, for example

```
In [817]: M.diagonal()
Out[817]: matrix([[ 0,  6, 12]])

In [818]: d.diagonal()
Out[818]: array([ 0,  6, 12])
```

`diagonal` has returned the same numbers, but for `M`, it returns an object of the same class, and which by class definition is 2d.

`d.T`, `M.I` access `properties`.  These don't require the `()` that a method does, but in many ways they are the same.  `np.matrix` has defined `I`, but `np.array` has not.

If you are used to working with matrices in MATLAB, the `np.matrix` class may ease the transition.  But if this is your first experience with arrays like this, I'd suggest sticking the `np.array`.  The `np.matrix` class will just add confusion.

---

`M.I` is the same as `M.getI()`.

It's code is (use `help(M.getI)` to read its docs)

```
def getI(self):
    M, N = self.shape
    if M == N:
        from numpy.dual import inv as func
    else:
        from numpy.dual import pinv as func
    return asmatrix(func(self))
```

So that means that `M.I` use `pinv` rather than `inv`.  `np.linalg.pinv(d)` works.

Answer (score 1):

You will get these methods if you transform `d` to a `np.matrix`, by doing:

```
d = np.matrix(d)
```

then:

```
d.I
d.diagonal()
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

`A.diagonal` is a method of numpy.ndarray, just as the print out suggests. Therefore, the solution of @Saullo Castro works for numpy arrays as well, without the need to convert to `np.matrix`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
diag = A.diagonal()
# array([ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24])
```

Numpy Arrays have no method to calculate the inverse of a matrix, but you can easily do that with `numpy.linalg.inv`, just as you already tried according to your code example.